# Optimization of Bar Plots in Matplotlib/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([770,215,179,107,83,82,70,60,57,54,52],index = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']) 

ax = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False,alpha=0.75, rot=45,fontsize=20)
ax.legend_.remove()
for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=0).astype(np.int64), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(2, 10), textcoords='offset points',fontsize=20)
ax.patches[df.index.get_indexer(['B'])[0]].set_facecolor('r')
ax.patches[df.index.get_indexer(['H'])[0]].set_facecolor('orange')
plt.ylabel('y ',fontsize=25)
plt.title('x',fontsize=30)
plt.show()
plt.save()
plt.close()
```

gave the following output graph:
[image]

The result is absolutely correct but I am not satisfied when a single bar 'A' at the front makes all the other bars so tiny and meaningless. Is there any way to optimize my chart in such a way that, 'B'-'K' appear bigger?. The thought I have in my mind is to split the graph in such a way that y-axis is 0-300 but from 300 to 800 it is 300..800. Or any other advices are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a logarithmic y-scale by providing `ax.set_yscale('log')`